# How to show a webpage modally

Tags: modal-dialog, html

There's website A. And there's a link saying "Click to open website B". Is it possible to opeb website B's webpage specified in the url link modally inside the website A? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe). You can then set the target property of your link to the name of your iframe.

```html
<iframe name="my_iframe"></iframe>
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="my_iframe">go to Google</a>
```